# Updating column values in PrimeFaces datatable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, myfaces

I have a datatable which contains items to be quoted on, and so has columns for quantity, unit price, etc and for which I want to display the total price for the item when the unit price is entered. My code looks like this:

```
<p:column styleClass="tdasheader" style="text-align:center" width="80" headerText="Unit Price">
    <pe:inputNumber id="unitPrice" value="#{quotedItem.quotedPrice}"
        minValue="0.01" maxValue="999999999.99" decimalPlaces="2"
        style="text-align: right;" size="10">

        <p:ajax event="change"
            listener="#{supplierQuotationBean.onAmountChange}"
            process="@this" update="totalPrice" />

        <f:attribute name="quotedItem" value="#{quotedItem}" />
    </pe:inputNumber>
</p:column>
<p:column styleClass="tdasheader" style="text-align:center" width="60" headerText="Disc" footerText="Total (inc Dly)">
    <pe:inputNumber id="discount" value="#{quotedItem.quotedDiscount}"
                            minValue="1" maxValue="100" />
</p:column>
<p:column styleClass="tdasheader" width="80" id="totalPriceCol">
    <f:facet name="header" style="text-align:center">
        <h:outputText value="Total" />
    </f:facet>
    <p:outputPanel id="totalPrice" style="text-align:right; padding-right:10px">
        <h:outputText value="#{quotedItem.totalPrice}">
            <f:convertNumber pattern="#,##0.00"/>
        </h:outputText>
    </p:outputPanel>
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:outputPanel style="text-align:right; padding-right:10px">
            <h:outputText value="x#{supplierQuotationBean.quotationTotalAsString}x" />
        </p:outputPanel>
    </f:facet>
</p:column>
```

As you may have guessed as I'm posting for help, the ajax update doesn't work - well, actually it works for the first row only. I've tried changing the value in the update parameter to "#{p:component('totalPrice')}" which does the same thing. I've even tried using the listener to do the update as follows:

```
String clientId = event.getComponent().getClientId();
String totalPriceClientId = clientId.substring(0, clientId.lastIndexOf(":"))+":totalPrice";
RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
requestContext.update(totalPriceClientId);
```

... but this doesn't work either. More significantly I guess, even if I update the whole datatable I still get the same result, but additionally lose the value in the unit price field (even with a process="@this")!

Can anyone please suggest how I might be able to overcome this problem?

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.1.15 and MyFaces 2.2.6.

Many thanks,
Neil

Comment: Could you please improve your example a bit (see [JSF MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info))? It would be nice to see more of the Facelets page, but without irrelevant tags (styleClass, decimalPlaces, etc.), and I'd also like to see the backing-bean.

Comment: You could also just try to `update` the whole `@form` if it seems the update behaviour is just "missing" some fields.

Comment: What does your ajax request and response look like (in both cases). And does the `totalPriceClientId` in the latter case start with a colon or not (it should not)

Comment: @DavidS All fair comments. Having tried to give a better example it turns out that for some reason the cause of it is a minValue parameter on a pe:inputNumber in another column (containing discount - now added to the example). Bizarre. The component is backed by a Double, but any minValue greater than 0 stops the update working. Remove minValue, or change the value to zero or less, and all works fine.

Comment: @Kukeltje It was a different column causing the problem as described in previous comment. Log shows 'Widget for var 'widget_quotationsForm_quotationLines_0_discount' not available!' - but only when there is a positive value for minValue. Strange.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back, Neil. I'm not surprised you found the problem (even if you can't explain it) while working on your example -- that usually happens to me too.

Comment: Neil, I wonder if the failure could have something to do with default values. The default value of a `double` is 0, so maybe it failed validation minValue right away?

Comment: adding a 'messages' tag if things do not work can often help in clarifying things

Comment: @DavidS yes you were right - default of zero was the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Kukeltje I do display any messages, but in this case there were none

Comment: @NeilRichards: But we cannot see (and there was no mention of it)...

Comment: @Kukeltje Fair enough :)